# Jenkins - Configure Jenkins to poll changes in SCM

Tags: jenkins

I am working with jenkins and I would like to run the maven goals when there is a change in the svn repository. I've attached a picture with my current configuration.

I know that checking the repository every 5 min is crazy. I would like to run it only when there is a new change, but I could not find the way. Anyway, it is not checking the repository. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I think your cron is not correct. According to what you described, you may need to change cron schedule to

```
*/5 * * * *
```

What you put in your schedule now mean it will poll the SCM at 5 past of every hour.

Comment: I have besides another questions, maybe you could help me: I hae problems with the authentification when I deploy the project. I dont know where to write the credentials. any clue? thankss

Comment: That is a web server specific question which I can't really answer

Comment: Hi Blanca, you could check the permissions that the jenkins' user has (maybe needs another user to run). On windows run `services.msc`, look for the jenkins project, right click, Properties -> Log on

Comment: Such a suttle change that makes a HUGE difference! (adding the */ before the 5 to go every 5 minutes instead of 5 minutes past the hour...)

Comment: Why does this get so many upvotes when its wrong?  The value "*/5" is the equivilant of "0-59/5", which is 12x per hour.

Answer (score 111):

I believe best practice these days is `H/5 * * * *`, which means every 5 minutes with a hashing factor to avoid all jobs starting at EXACTLY the same time.

Comment: Indeed, Jenkins (two years later) will now throw the following warning `Spread load evenly by using ‘H/5 * * * *’ rather than ‘*/5 * * * *’`.

Comment: yes using H/5 * * * * is the best practice to avoid error  "Spread load evenly by using ‘H/5 * * * *’ rather than ‘*/5 * * * *"

Answer (score 8):

That's an old question, I know. But, according to me, it is missing proper answer.

The actual / optimal workflow here would be to incorporate SVN's post-commit hook so it triggers Jenkins job after the actual commit is issued only, not in any other case. This way you avoid unneeded polls on your SCM system.

You may find the following links interesting:

- Jenkins Wiki's [post-commit hook description](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin#SubversionPlugin-Post-commithook) on Subversion Plugin's doc-site. Here you find documented example of the script you are interested in.
- [Hook-scripts contrib directory](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/) in the source of official Apache Foundation's Subversion's source control repository.
- [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194621/post-commit-hook-to-trigger-automatic-jenkins-build) on StackOverflow.

In case of my setup in the corp's SVN server, I utilize the following (censored) script as a post-commit hook on the subversion server side:

```
#!/bin/sh

# POST-COMMIT HOOK

REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
#TXN_NAME="$3"
LOGFILE=/var/log/xxx/svn/xxx.post-commit.log

MSG=$(svnlook pg --revprop $REPOS svn:log -r$REV)
JENK="http://jenkins.xxx.com:8080/job/xxx/job/xxx/buildWithParameters?token=xxx&username=xxx&cause=xxx+r$REV"
JENKtest="http://jenkins.xxx.com:8080/view/all/job/xxx/job/xxxx/buildWithParameters?token=xxx&username=xxx&cause=xxx+r$REV"

echo post-commit $* >> $LOGFILE 2>&1

# trigger Jenkins job - xxx
svnlook changed $REPOS -r $REV | cut -d' ' -f4 | grep -qP "branches/xxx/xxx/Source"
if test 0 -eq $? ; then
        echo $(date) - $REPOS - $REV: >> $LOGFILE
        svnlook changed $REPOS -r $REV | cut -d' ' -f4 | grep -P "branches/xxx/xxx/Source" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
        echo logmsg: $MSG >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
        echo curl -qs $JENK >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
        curl -qs $JENK >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
        echo -------- >> $LOGFILE
fi

# trigger Jenkins job - xxxx
svnlook changed $REPOS -r $REV | cut -d' ' -f4 | grep -qP "branches/xxx_TEST"
if test 0 -eq $? ; then
        echo $(date) - $REPOS - $REV: >> $LOGFILE
        svnlook changed $REPOS -r $REV | cut -d' ' -f4 | grep -P "branches/xxx_TEST" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
        echo logmsg: $MSG >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
        echo curl -qs $JENKtest >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
        curl -qs $JENKtest >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
        echo -------- >> $LOGFILE
fi

exit 0
```