# JMeter - open a jmx file from web

Tags: jmeter

I know I can download file from web, but in case that I want to get the updated jmx files in 1 machine (get from source control only once using trigger) and load it on different machines, 
Can I open in JMeter a jmx file located in web?

I'm trying but failing (with different escaping) from http://jmeter.apache.org/demos:

```
jmeter -t "http://jmeter.apache.org/demos/forEachTestPlan.jmx"

2017-09-28 09:09:53,527 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Failure loading test file
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:\jmeter.apache.org\demos\forEachTestPlan.jmx (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.loadTree(SaveService.java:423) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startGui(JMeter.java:386) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:519) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:248) [ApacheJMeter.jar:3.3 r1808647]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't OOTB, you need another tool

You could use a curl or wget to get a local copy then run it.

What is the use case ?

Comment: Get the updated jmx files in 1 machine (get from source control only once in trigger) and load it on different machines

Comment: You would need for now to do it through some shell. Maybe you can discuss this on dev mailing list

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting your JMeter script under [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) management, Jenkins has ability to [poll version control systems on schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121098/jenkins-configure-jenkins-to-poll-changes-in-scm) (or alternatively you can use a [VCS hook](http://kohsuke.org/2011/12/01/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-from-a-git-hook/)) so Jenkins will scan the target version control system for any updates and if they are - it will checkout the latest .jmx file version and run JMeter test using it.

See [Continuous Integration 101: How to Run JMeter With Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins) for more information on JMeter and Jenkins integration.

Comment: If I want to execute Jenkins with slaves how can I get the jmx file from specific machine?